# Karate DSL - How to read token string from __arg and send this string in json request?

Tags: javascript, java, json, dsl, karate

How to read token string from __arg and send this string in json request using Karate DSL?

Store string token value from first response to __arg

and this works well:

```
    Then match response.result.token == '#string'

    * def tokenPathInstance =
    """
    function() { karate.write(response.result.token, '__arg'); }
    """
    * def tokenPath = call tokenPathInstance
```

But for the next json request I've tried the next one code but this doesn't work for my needs:

```
 def jsonInstance =
"""
function(token) {
  var DTO = Java.type('requestbody.DTO');
  var li = new DTO();
  li.setToken(token);
  return li.toJson();
}
"""
 def token = read('file:target/__arg')
 def reqBody = call jsonInstance token
```

I only see in request :
"token": "java.io.FileInputStream@693dc9dc",

Comment: you need to put more work into your question: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @antony-nick: Would be great if you could provide a self running scenario the next time that unveils the issue. This makes it easy to reproduce the error or fix your example.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug. Created https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1009

When embedding a unknown (not json, yaml, csv aso.) read resource into a pure js expression like a json, the result looks like:

```
{
  "token": {
    "tokenParam": "java.io.FileInputStream@424bd12a"
  }
}
```

Writing the token as a txt file is a workaround. The mime type detection just checks for the suffix.

The following scenario should explain that:

```
Scenario: Test to read/write within karate..
    * def token = 'xyz12345'
    * eval  karate.write(karate.get('token'), 'token.txt'); 
    * def tokenToJson = 
    """
      function(tokenParam) {
        return { token: tokenParam}
      }
    """

    * string tokenFromFile = read('file:target/token.txt')
    * def tokenAsJson = call tokenToJson tokenFromFile
    * print tokenAsJson
    * match tokenAsJson == {token: '#(token)'}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks! I would try this workaround and write it back here.